# como recupero el texto de un input text

Tags: typescript, svg, d3.js

como puedo recuperar todo texto que estoy tecleando? y mostrarlo en algun console.log

intente con el evento key up pero solo me muestra caracter.

‘'

```
    export function func() {
        let gCajatexto = this as d3.Selection<any, any, any, any>;
        gCajatexto.classed("gctexto", true);

        let rect = gCajatexto.append("g")
        rect.append("foreignObject")
            .attr("x", "100")
            .attr("y", "100")
            .attr("width", 150)
            .attr("height", 30)
            .html(function (d) {

                return '<input type="password" value="ok" />'
               //como recupero lo que tiene el input text y mostrarlo en el console.log
            })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

en ves de usar onkeyup utiliza keydown eso te dara los caracteres al presionar la tecla o prueba esto

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("id del texbox");

texBox.addEventListener("keydown",()=>{
    console.log(textBox.value);
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos... Puedes ayudarlo con código... Le será más fácil al OP entender la solución

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: eso ya corregí, lo que quiero es recuperar lo que esta en la caja de texto

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por informarme